# Oracle aggregate function performance

Tags: oracle, performance

Can Oracle be smart about aggregate functions, such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, and `(AVG)`?  My testing shows that it seems to be surprisingly stupid.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(userId), AVG(age), 
 STDDEV(age), MIN(age), MAX(age), 
 date_range_start, date_range_end
FROM users
WHERE
(date_range_start >= TO_DATE('01-Dec-2010')) AND (date_range_end <= TO_DATE('30-Nov-2011')) 
GROUP BY date_range_start, date_range_end;
```

It takes 27 seconds.
Now I remove the `STDDEV`, `MIN` and `MAX` aggregations the same query takes only 12 seconds.
OK, I can see `STDDEV` slowing things down as it requires 2 passes.
So I try `AVG` + `MIN` and `MAX` -- I get 21s.

How is this even possible?  How can adding calculation of min and max to the calculation of AVG slow things down by the factor of 2 almost?  Considering that out of the 12 seconds that it takes with AVG only 10 are spent on the full table scan?  So adding min/max calculation changes the group by step from 2 seconds to 10?

The explain plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation      | Name         | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |              |      1 |        |     12 |00:00:24.61 |     369K|    369K|   |   |      |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |              |      1 |     12 |     12 |00:00:24.61 |     369K|    369K|   762K|   762K|   11M (0)|
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| USER         |      1 |     29M|     29M|00:00:09.34 |     369K|    369K|   |   |      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: do you have a tkprof/xplan showing this behaviour?

Comment: @NiallLitchfield I have the xplan (updated), I can't get tkprof at the moment.

Comment: How many rows does the query return?

Comment: @ypercube the table above contains 2 columns: E-Rows and A-Rows.  E-Rows stands for "Estimated Rows", A stands for "Actual".  So the query returns 12 rows.

Comment: Is this always true: `date_range_start <= date_range_end` ?

Comment: the standard deviation can be calcualted in one pass (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance)

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle analytics:

```
SELECT distinct
  COUNT(userId) over (partition by date_range_start, date_range_end)
, AVG(age)      over (partition by date_range_start, date_range_end)
, STDDEV(age)   over (partition by date_range_start, date_range_end)
, MIN(age)      over (partition by date_range_start, date_range_end)
, MAX(age)      over (partition by date_range_start, date_range_end)
, date_range_start, date_range_end
FROM users
WHERE
(date_range_start >= TO_DATE('01-Dec-2010')) AND (date_range_end <= TO_DATE('30-Nov-2011')) 
/
```

It does the same but most of the times it is surprizingly faster.

Answer (score 0):

If `userId` cannot be NULL, change `COUNT(userId)` to `COUNT(*)`.

If `date_range_start <= date_range_end` is true for all rows, then you could slightly change the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(age), 
 STDDEV(age), MIN(age), MAX(age), 
 date_range_start, date_range_end
FROM users
WHERE (date_range_start BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Dec-2010') AND TO_DATE('30-Nov-2011')) 
  AND (date_range_end <= TO_DATE('30-Nov-2011')) 
GROUP BY date_range_start, date_range_end ;
```

If you have an index on `date_range_start`, the change will help narrowing the search.

I would also think that an index on `(date_range_start, date_range_end, age)` would be most helpful for this query but Oracle behaves so much different than MySQL that I may be totally wrong.